# Publish Data via Kafka with Palantir Foundry

Tags: palantir-foundry

We would like to publish data (records of an dataset) via Kafka to our enterprise service bus. We are on Prem. I know that it is possible to consume data via Kafka, but I have not found any documentation on how to publish it. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know any publicly documented kafka exports. Maybe if you reach out internally your Palantir counterparts will have something. If something becomes available I'll come back here and add as an answer :)